# Symlinks aren't working on macOS

Tags: macos

i got a problem with Symlinks which i should create to install Typo as in this Guide
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/singlehtml/

When they are created they don't seem to point anywhere.

Can someone help me?
Morishno

Answer (score 0):

First things first, restart your computer.

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of any possible issue that'd cause the problem described in the question, which would be fixed by restarting. Can you explain your reasoning, or is this just a shot in the dark?

Comment: It's always a safe bet, especially after installing software.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution. I tried to create the Symlink in a Symlink so the path was incorrect.